# Ionic CLI not respecting --v2 tag

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I'm a long time Ionic user and set out to start my first Ionic 2 app. [The docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/cli/) say that this will work:

```
$ npm install -g ionic@beta
$ ionic -v => 1.7.10
$ ionic start newApp --v2
```

But when I run it my `newApp` is v1? I am running Node 4.1.

Comment: Can you do a `which ionic`? Looks it could be a conflict. Or close the terminal and open it again

Comment: /Users/---/.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.0/bin/ionic - thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP just needed to close the terminal and open it again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @mhartington - needed to close and reopen my terminal!

Comment: Just added the answer in my own post. Please mark as correct.